# Can't make Bevel Modifier working on engraved mesh

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I'm trying to bevel the mesh with bevel modifier, for the text area marked red, but the modifier doesn't work,

[image]

Even if I apply the bevel modifier on the whole mesh in object mode, it doesn't work either,

[image]

I don't know what goes wrong, what I want to achieve is to bevel the engraved text area, to make it smooth.

Comment: This has to do with the bool operation (I assume) you performed to get that "engraved" look. If you look now, the top of your mesh is split into (what looks like) 2 large faces, each with a large number of vertices that are unconnected from the inner edge (text) to the outer edge (side of the "block"). Essentially, the top faces of your mesh are large n-gons and blender prefers quad based topology (4 verts per face) in order to function properly. This is why you cannot bevel.

Comment: If I take a closer look, it has very little bevels, but the width is too narrow to be seen, even the width set to 100m

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the “clamp overlap” in the modifier. This has gotten me a few times too.

Comment: Yes, but it will cause face overlap

Comment: It’s an existing problem in blender that may have a solution but I don’t know about it. It’s kind of a geometric problem when two outward corners intersect with one inner corner.

Comment: Come to think of it, that’s a question worth asking. I think I’ll delete my answer, and go ask it now, or you can?

Comment: Leave this answer here, cause we can use this solution if tiny intersected faces are less important